# Deny access to ssi files

Tags: .htaccess, ssi

I'm using SSI on my website.
I have got html files which represent my site and shtml files which I include into some of these html files using the `include` command of SSI.
Is there any way to deny users from seeing the shtml files which I include?
I tried the following:

```xml
<FilesMatch "\.(shtml?)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>
```

And here is the whole part of my current htaccess file which may be important:

```xml
allow from all
<Files ~ "^\.htaccess|^README\.txt">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
<FilesMatch "\.(shtml?)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>

AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
```